# How do I summarise and bind large data sets in parallel using tidyverse in R?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, bind, doparallel

I have a couple of large daily datasets that I need to summarise and bind in R by month. Because the datasets are so large, I'd like to do the summarising in parallel so that it is faster. I've been successful in summarise and binding them with a regular loop, but the summarising portion takes all night.

The dataset looks something like this:

```
number     id   date
1      1        0102
1      1        0102
2      1        0102
2      2        0102
```

and I want

```
number     id   day    count
1      1        0102    2
2      1        0102    1
2      2        0102   1
```

```
collapse_cdr<- function(data){
  dta<- data %>% 
    group_by(number,date, id) %>%
    summarise(count=n())  %>%
    mutate(total.calls=sum(count)) %>%
    slice(which.max(count))
  
  }
```

```
wd<-("working directory")

cl <- makeCluster(8)
registerDoParallel(cl)
month = foreach(i=day_code, .combine=rbind, .packages=c("tidyverse","readr")) %dopar%
 { filename<-paste0(wd,"/", i, ".csv")
    dta<-read_csv(filename, col_types = cols(.default = "c"))
    dta$date <- i
    dta<-collapse_cdr(data=dta)
    data.frame(dta)
  }
```

Right now I'm getting the warning closing unused connection 62 (<-localhost:11439)

Thank you!

Comment: Your function `collapse_cdr()` does not use either of the arguments passed to it. Notice that `collapse_cdr(mtcars, "rteam22")` will return the same result as `collapse_cdr(dta,"0102")`

Comment: @langtang Good catch! Unfortunately that didn't fix anything! Updated to show new version

Comment: You might shorten your function to `data %>% count(number, date, id, sort = TRUE)  %>% mutate(total.calls = sum(n)) %>% slice(1)`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest an approach using data.table

```
library(data.table)
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

# Function to collapse the data
collapse_cdr <- function(d) {
  d[, .(count=.N), .(number,date,id)][
    ,total.calls:=sum(count), .(number,date)][
      , .SD[which.max(count)], .(number,date)]
}

wd<-("working directory")

cl <- makeCluster(8)
registerDoParallel(cl)
month = rbindlist(
  foreach(i=day_code) %dopar% {
    collapse_cdr(fread(paste0(wd,"/", i, ".csv"))[, date:=i])
  }
)
stopCluster(cl)
```